# Escalate error occurring inside an actor outside of the actor system

Tags: akka.net

We use Akka.NET in a part of a WPF application. We currently have no way of properly utilizing Akka's fault tolerance, though, so we need any errors occurring in actors to actually cause exceptions outside the actor system. However, I have not been able to find out how to achieve that.

In the supervisor actor for the actor throwing the test error, I have set the supervisor strategy as such:

```cs
protected override SupervisorStrategy SupervisorStrategy() =>
    AllForOneStrategy(ex => Directive.Escalate);
```

As I have read, this is insufficient, and it is also necessary to set the supervision strategy for the user guardian via HOCON configuration. As there is no other configuration yet, I am creating it like this:

```cs
var config =
    ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(
        @"akka.actor.guardian-supervisor-strategy = ""Akka.Actor.StoppingSupervisorStrategy""");
```

This is then passed to the `ActorSystem` constructor. It does not cause anything different to happen when an exception occurs within an actor, though.

How can I prevent Akka from protecting the application from exceptions raised inside the actor system?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. If you want to terminate ActorSystem in case of some child failed with task: 1) escalate, catch that error in your "roor" actor and terminate system. But that's not what Akka designed for. If you want exception message, just `Ask` actor to do something and if it may fail do `Sender.Tell(new Status.Failure(exception));` and wait for exception object on the other side.